# Stack Overflow HTTP passing through some workplace firewall

Tags: support, feature-request, mobile-web, accessibility, web-sockets

My workplace uses a strict HTTP firewall that only provide scanned versions of original websites, and not the original website itself. There is no way to bypass it since it is enforced on the system level and browser level too.

The issue is that, while this scanning retains most of Stack Overflow functions, I have issues with toolbars in the answer box and also can't "add comment" to any post/answers. I still can answer, but that's just a pain without the toolbar. I believe because the toolbars and "add comments" require JavaScript or ajax/axios something? I didn't take a look at the website source code so I'm just guessing.

Is there any mobile/lite version or something of Stack Overflow where I can access these features that can successfully pass through my workplace firewall?

I know this is probably not a popular issue due to most workplaces being flexible. But, it'd be great help if there is a solution since I have lot of free time during work and would love to contribute to this community.

Comment: What you're basically asking for here is for SO to be fully functional for you when you're in an environment where the site has been intentionally broken by your company's IT department in some way which anyone other than you or others at your company don't actually know and can't test in. That doesn't seem like a reasonable thing to ask SO, the company, to do as a feature request. It might be possible for you to recover the functionality you desire, but what's going to be necessary will depend on what your company is *really* doing and what you're allowed to do.

Comment: The generalized way to fix this is to ask your IT department to whitelist all of the domains which SO/SE requires for operation. You can find a list of the domains in [answer to: "Can we have a list of all the Stack Exchange domains somewhere, for firewall purposes?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81383/271271)

Answer (score 8):

That you can't add comments is probably due to not having the privilege yet, which comes at 50 reputation. A missing toolbar is a sign of at least one JavaScript file not being available. You can use the Developer Console of your browser to verify which file it is. Maybe providing that info to your IT admins allows them to tweak a setting to resolve your issue.

Now for your main question:

> Is there any mobile/lite version or something of Stack Overflow where I can access these features that can successfully pass through my workplace firewall?

No, there is not. There used to be a [Mobile view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367609/deprecating-our-mobile-views) but ...

> On March 2, 2022 we removed the Mobile button from the footer. This means the mobile views are removed entirely from Stack Overflow. Last week, we also removed the Disable Responsiveness button.

... so we all got very responsive instead.

See also the "What else do I need" section of [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161)

If you have to edit a post without the toolbar you might find these posts useful:

- [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites)
- [We're switching to CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark)
- [New Feature: Table Support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support)